# Does Source Insight provide "EOL conversion" function?

Tags: source-insight

In Notepad++, there is an "EOL Conversion" option which can change the `EOL` of a file from Windows into Unix format. Does Source Insight provide the similar feature which can convert a file or a bunch of files in batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer is from `Source Insight` support:

> To save a file with a specific end-of-line type in Source Insight, select *File* > *Save As...*, then where it says "*Save as type*", select the desired end-of-line type.
>
> To set the end-of-line type for new files you create in Source Insight, select *Options* > *Preferences* and click the *Files* tab. Where it says "*Default file format*" select the desired end-of-line type.